# Parsing and rendering markdown from Strapi into Sveltekit app

Tags: svelte, strapi, sveltekit

I have a Strapi CMS as well as a sveltekit app running the front end. Its my first time to use both and I realised Strapi uses Markdown. I looked around fr a svelte plugin that could assist but most either use a file or code in the script tag versus the info I get from strapi.

Help!